# I tried to rewrite a URL but its not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to manipulate the URLs in my site. For example, I want to rewrite this URL `profile/anything/about` to `profile/anything` but it not just working, it shows my Page Not Found constructed page, here is my `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pageNotFound.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    Option +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/about profile/$1/index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me out, am new to this

Comment: To which page does `profile/anything/about` actually get redirected?

Comment: @Tim Its redirected to `profile/anything/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see anything bad in your code but it didn't work for me also, but here is the trick. If "L" is included among your flags just make sure that the next line is commented. It worked for me.

And I think you should use the `match any of contents` = [] instead of `any character`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pageNotFound.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    Option +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/about profile/$1/index.php [NC,L]
    #this is a commented line after the LAST RULE flag
</IfModule>
```